# Как в SSL предотвращается подделка сеансового ключа?

Tags: ssl, https

Если я правильно понял, то алгоритм "рукопожатия" следующий:

1. сервер генерирует публичный (шифрующий) и приватный (дешифрующий) ключи;
2. сервер отправляет публичный ключ клиенту;
3. клиент генерирует сеансовый ключ и шифрует его публичным ключом;
4. клиент отправляет зашифрованный сеансовый ключ серверу;
5. сервер дешифрует зашифрованный сеансовый ключ приватным ключом.

В итоге, весь дальнейший трафик шифруется/дешифруется сеансовым ключом.

Но представим такую ситуацию:

1. сервер отправляет публичный ключ клиенту;
2. злоумышленник перехватывает публичный ключ;
3. злоумышленник генерирует поддельный сеансовый ключ и шифрует его публичным ключом;
4. злоумышленник отправляет зашифрованный поддельный сеансовый ключ серверу;
5. сервер дешифрует зашифрованный поддельный сеансовый ключ приватным ключом.

Трафик между сервером и фейковым клиентом начинает передаваться.

Либо я что-то не до конца понимаю, либо алгоритм работает несколько сложнее, чем я описал выше.

Comment: Вы пропустили шаг 1.5 публичный ключ подписывается удостоверяющим центром (lets encrypt, thatwe и т.п) и клиенту посылается подписанный  публичный ключ. Клиент проверяет валидность подписи и если он не валиден показывает пользователю ошибку.

Comment: А в остальном вы описали типовую атаку «человек посередине» (man in the middle) и литературы по этому вопросу полный гугл